# How can I create a custom function in Google Sheets to calculate rowing speed from time and distance inputs?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Javascript custom function for google sheets calculating rowing speed

I am looking to create a function in google sheets that takes in time formatted as (mm:ss.00) and distance (in meters) and calculates speed. In rowing, we calculate speed as Time per 500 meters and it is denominated the same as above (mm:ss.00)

I am new to JS and couldn't get JS to convert time as inputted above into seconds to perform the calc.